# Quartz-Job in grails does not work when deployed to JBoss 7

Tags: grails, jboss, jboss7.x

I'm trying to deploy a grails-app (2.2.4) to a JBoss AS 7.1.1.

I built my war file via `grails war`, copied it to the directory standalone/deployments and started JBoss with bin/standalone.bat.

This far everything works fine, the site is accessible with the browser. But one part of the application is a quartz-job which should load a file from an FTP-server.

It starts regularly as expected but it fails because of the following error:

```
ERROR [grails.plugins.quartz.listeners.ExceptionPrinterJobListener] (quartzScheduler_Worker-6) Exception occurred in job: null: org.quartz.JobExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/BuildLogger [See nested exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/BuildLogger]
    at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:96) [classes:]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213) [quartz-2.1.5.jar:]
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557) [quartz-2.1.5.jar:]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/BuildLogger
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1853) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$2$1.run(CachedClass.java:69) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$2.initValue(CachedClass.java:66) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$2.initValue(CachedClass.java:64) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:33) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass.getConstructors(CachedClass.java:258) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.<init>(MetaClassImpl.java:187) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.<init>(ExpandoMetaClass.java:297) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.<init>(ExpandoMetaClass.java:340) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClassCreationHandle.createNormalMetaClass(ExpandoMetaClassCreationHandle.java:46) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.createWithCustomLookup(MetaClassRegistry.java:147) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.create(MetaClassRegistry.java:130) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:175) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:192) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:309) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getMetaClass(InvokerHelper.java:806) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallConstructorSite(CallSiteArray.java:84) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:186) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at projectname.MessungImportJob$_ftpFileRetrieval_closure1.doCall(MessungImportJob.groovy:183) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:425) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1326) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1298) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$148.invoke(Unknown Source) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116) [groovy-all-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at projectname.MessungImportJob.ftpFileRetrieval(MessungImportJob.groovy:115) [classes:]
    at projectname.MessungImportJob$ftpFileRetrieval.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at projectname.MessungImportJob.execute(MessungImportJob.groovy:77) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:89) [classes:]
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.BuildLogger from [Module "deployment.projectname-0.1.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 54 more
```

I suppose this is a rather basic Java-Question, but nevertheless: Do I have to include this org.apache.tools.ant-library somewhere? Do I have to "list" it somewhere in the grails-configs? Or am I missing something completely else?

Starting it in developer-mode (`grails run-app`) works fine.

Thanks for your proposals,
Marius

Comment: Is this any help? http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Tomcat7-deployment-InvokerInvocationException-NoClassDefFoundError-for-BuildLogger-td4640697.html

Comment: I tried some ways of including this package ('compile ":org.apache.ant:ant:1.9.2"' as plugins or as dependencies in BuildConfig.groovy) but it didn't help, error remains. When compiling there's also a message: 'Error WARNING: Specified dependency definition compile(:org.apache.ant:ant:1.9.2) is invalid! Skipping..'

Comment: Have you tried running `grails refresh-dependencies` after that?

Comment: I needed ant _and_ ant-launcher and had to remove the colon at the beginning. Now it works, but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason and a solution on this site: http://grails.org/plugin/grails-ant

Even though ant is part of Grails core, since it's primarily a build tool, it's not included in a Grails war file (1). And you can do that in your own app, without this plugin, by adding ant to your build.config.

```
dependencies {
    // Workarounds for Grails not shipping ant in WAR
    compile 'org.apache.ant:ant:1.7.1'    //you can also use runtime
    compile 'org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.7.1' 
}
```

I changed the versions to the most recent ones from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ant) and JBoss starts it.

Thanks to tim_yates for the first hint.